# How can I resolve the 'LF will be replaced by CRLF' error when committing large files in Git?

Tags: github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACs9A.png)

Hello, I hope you understand the mistranslation because I used a translator.(thank u:D)
I was trying to commit a large file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To4nt.png)

However, as shown in the picture, two files showed an error.
So I proceeded with the commit except for those files, and there was no problem.
But I needed those files, so I searched for errors and wrote down the necessary commands.

$git config --global core.autocrlf true --> code

but still the problem is not solved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b1Mq.png)

When I clicked on those files, I got this message.
By following the file path, only the files with errors were found to be different from other files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHPB9.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnIhe.png)

I didn't know, so I changed the picture file to png format, but there was still a problem.
how can i fix it?
I don't know much about these things, so I need a detailed answer.
Thank you very much for reading my long question !!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please replace the links by text (if possible) or by embedded images? Links to images are strongly discouraged.